# VB.net ISo DateFormat

Tags: vb.net

I have a date in VB.net that is stored in ISO 8601 format

```
'Date here is local time in germany   
Dim s As String = "2010-09-27T16:54:28+02:00"

Dim dt As DateTime
If Date.TryParse(s, dt) = True Then

End If
```

When I use try to parse it shows me date in my local timezone,

how can I get date as

2010-9-27 4:54 PM as well as GMT DATE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A date is not stored internally with any specific representation.

You need to format it for display, using the correct `DateTime` format string (either [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) or [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)):

```
Dim s As String = "2010-09-27T16:54:28+02:00"

Dim dt As DateTime
If Date.TryParse(s, dt) = True Then
    Dim gmt as String = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim custom as String = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-M-d h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
End If
```

Comment: If I do dt.ToLocalTime it gives me "09/27/2010 04:54:28" which is coorect but without am or PM

Comment: @cshah - `DateTime.ToString` will default to local system settings for its formatting unless defined, so you need to tell it what culture to use. i have updated my answer to reflect this.