# working with time formats for GMT offset

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Is it possible to determine from looking at datetime value whether it is local time or GMT with the offset? I have no idea about this and pretty embarrassed to say it out loud.

```
<time>2012-11-07T15:22:31Z</time>
```

Now I need to show this time in GMT with its offset for local time. Am I just to assume that his is local time and what is the Z & T for>

EDIT

Thanks for the links. So what would the following be

2012-11-09T12:34:02+00:00

is that the offset for UTC

Comment: Do you write the code which generataes that time stamp?

Comment: Check this out,  Should not be any different in VB. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Here is an answer for VB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265092/how-to-convert-utc-datetime-column-to-local-time-in-datagridview (BTW: It is UTC time with the Z on it) - More info here: http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/

Comment: no I dont I parse that time out of an xml feed....I do create another time stamp for when I do this and it is in this format 2012-11-07 15:22:00 using parsedate.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is time presentation in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

**T** is is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.

and

**Z** is the second designator that follows the value for the number of seconds.

To convert ISO 8601 to to local or UTC write a custom converter like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834617/vb-net-iso-dateformat)